# New version of NuGet not working on VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

I've downloaded ASP.NET MVC 3 RC and the new NuGet CTP version.

When I try to install anything in the thru the Package Manager Console I get the an error message. Here are two samples:

```
PM> nip elmah
Install-Package : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:4
+ nip <<<<  elmah
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGet.VisualStudio.Cmdlets.InstallPackageCmdlet


PM> nip SQLCE.EntityFramework
Install-Package : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:4
+ nip <<<<  SQLCE.EntityFramework
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGet.VisualStudio.Cmdlets.InstallPackageCmdlet
```

When I use the Add Library Package Reference in the Solution Explorer no message is displayed but the package is not installed.

I tried to revert to NuPack and it works fine but the Package list is not updated (for instance SQLCE.EntityFramework 4.0.8435.1 is not been displayed only 4.0.8402.1).

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. Deleting my packages folder fixed it.

Comment: The "packages" folder is located beside the solution file.  I was in the project folder and it took a few minutes for me to track down the "packages" folder.  Deleting this folder solved the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

I experienced exactly the same problem.

In the end I had to remove everything from the packages directory and go through each project and run an "update-package" for each package I had previously installed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pointing to the old feed by any chance? Or an old local feed?

Comment: No. I was very carefull to point to the new feed. But I don't think that the problem is on the feed. It looks like an internal problem of the library.

Answer (score 0):

**I also had this problem.**

I solved it by ensuring that I did packed with the nuspec and dll in the same folder and the nuspec name was mydll.dll.nuspec. When I deviated from this I got said error.